# Umlauts in the bibliography file of LaTeX

Tags: latex, bibtex

I use Mendeley to manage my bibliography for my thesis. I add all the papers there and then I have it create a file bibtex to then use in the writing of the thesis.
One of the citation I need is Röthlisberger et al., 2000a, since I knew LaTeX would have freaked out if I dared to simply write the ö in the BibTeX file, I edited (using .tex editor on windows) the entry to be

```
@article{Roth2000,
author = {Regine R{\"{o}}thlisberger and Manuel A. Hutterli and Stefan Sommer and Eric W. Wolff and Robert Mulvaney},
   doi = {10.1029/2000JD900264},
   issn = {01480227},
   issue = {D16},
   journal = {Journal of Geophysical Research: Atmospheres},
   month = {8},
   title = {Factors controlling nitrate in ice cores: Evidence from the Dome C deep ice core},
   volume = {105},
   year = {2000},
}
```

Since I'm using natbib (\usepackage[round]{natbib}), the process of citing should be quite straightforward and in the text I used \citep{Roth2000} to call the citation where I needed and...
It doesn't work.
At all.
I tried all the combination to write the ö in that name, with multiple brackets, without brackets, only on the o, all of them. The result is always an error of

```
!Missing $ inserted. 
<inserted text>
$
l.19 R.~R<?>

<?>thlisberger, U...
?
```

which makes, to me, no sense. I tried to look around and every guide I've found seems to suggest that... this is how you should write it. Am I missing something?

EDIT:

The file I'm trying to make work is as follows

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt,titlepage]{book}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}                                  
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                        
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}                             


\title{Title}
\author{Raffaello Nardin}
\date {October 2021}



\begin{document}


\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \citep{Roth2000}

\bibliography{Ref}


\end{document}
```

With Ref being the name of the BibTeX file

Comment: Can you make a [mre] ?

Comment: I tried to add all of what I think are the relevant information, I'm fairly new to LaTeX having used it only for very few short essay where I could write every quote by hand

Comment: Thanks! Your example works for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNT6f.png a) can you check if your files are indeed encoded in applemac and not, say, utf8? This would be very unusual this century. b) can you show the .log file you get from the short example in your question?

Comment: Thank you, htf8 works. I don't know why but honestly, I'm a bit too stressed and short on time to even care haha!

Comment: Great to hear it is working. Good luck with your thesis!